# How can i find the index of the largest value input in a 2d array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I need help in trying to find the index of the largest element. The user first enters the size of the 2d array, then the user inputs the elements in an array. Then the program would display the location of the largest array.

However, I have this code below and am having trouble in printing out the index location of the largest element in the array. It just returns as 0,0.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int row, column;
    int r,c;
    
    cout << "Enter the number of rows of the array: ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Enter the number of column of the array: ";
    cin >> column;
    cout << "\nEnter the array: " << endl;
    
    double table[row][column];
    
    for ( r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    
        for ( c = 0; c < column; c++) {
                cin >> table[row][column];
        }
        
    }

int rr=0,cc=0;
int max;
     

     
    for ( r = 0; r < row; r++){
        
        if (table[rr][cc] < table[r][c]) {
            
            rr=r;}
            
            for ( c = 0; c <column; c++){
            
             
                if (table[rr][cc] < table[r][c]) {
                
                cc=c;

                }
                
            } 
    }
    
    cout << "\nLocation of the largest array: " << rr << ","<< cc << endl;
    
}
```

Comment: `cin >> table[row][column];` is wrong, it should be `cin >> table[r][c];`.

Comment: `double table[row][column];` is invalid C++ (use VLA extension). use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for pointing it out. I should have declared variables more properly so that confusion would have been avoided. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You should first move `r` and `c` to search for the satisfying element, and then check if the elements satisifies the condition.

```
    for ( r = 0; r < row; r++){
        // remove this, or you will access out-of-range because c will be column here
        //if (table[rr][cc] < table[r][c]) {
            
        //    rr=r;}
            
            for ( c = 0; c <column; c++){
            
             
                if (table[rr][cc] < table[r][c]) {
                
                rr=r; // also update rr here
                cc=c;

                }
                
            } 
    }
```

Also, as @Jarod42  pointed out, the input part `cin >> table[row][column];` is also wrong. It should be `cin >> table[r][c];`, or another out-of-range access will be invoked there.

Comment: Reducing variable scope would catch the first issue.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for pointing it out. I should have declared variables more properly so that confusion would have been avoided. Thanks for the help !